# nodejs twitter stream The "listener" argument must be of type Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, async-await

I am trying to fetch twitter stream data using `nodejs` and `twit` package.

Here's the code I found in a tutorial:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'vscode' });

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
    console.log(tweet);
});
```

Here's what I tried as its equivalent in `async-await` format:

```
private streamPublicTweets = async (request:Request, response:Response)=>{    
    const stream: any = await this.T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'vscode' });
    const data = await stream.on('tweet');
    console.log(data)
}
```

I get this error which is very much expected.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
```

How do I fix this issue in my code?

Comment: you can't await just anything that is asynchronous .... you can await a Promise - neither of the functions you `await` return a Promise - and, the first code example will log any tweet (1 or more), the code you attempted, if it were possible, would only ever console.log the first tweet

Comment: The error is due to the fact that `.on` must have at least two arguments, the "event" and the listener function - you fail to supply the listener function, hence it is `undefined` and hence the error - to be honest, not everything can be made into Promises - and this is one example of something that Promises does not fit the purpose